# Meteor Dashboard and publication/subscription

Tags: meteor

EDIT: as the original question was too vague I have updated it to make it more concrete

I'd like to create a dashboard in Meteor that shows some statistics about my collections (e.g. how many docs, how many users...). I have been trying the past days but can't seem to find a good/intelligent way.

I initially just did the following:

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
  getProductsCount: function() {
    return Products.find().count();
  }
});
```

This did not work. I think because it counts the number of products from minimongo, but not sure.

Then I did the following:

- In the template helper, call a method and get the value to show on the dashboard page (does not work)
- Was told not to use pub/sub mechanism for this type of metric
- Worked via Session variables (did work, but feels a bit strange to store this kind of metric data in Session variables

So then I read in another SO response about Reactive Variables and tried the following:

```
Template.dashboard.helpers({
  getProductsCount: function() {
    return Template.instance().myAsyncValue.get();
  }
});

Template.dashboard.created = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.myAsyncValue = new ReactiveVar("Waiting for response from server");
  Meteor.call('getProductsCount', function(error, asyncValue){
    if (error)
      console.log(error);
    else
      self.myAsyncValue.set(asyncValue);
  });
};
```

This works, but I find this extremely difficult for something as simple as showing a product count (or any other metric). Not sure I understand the reason why I should use sth as reactive variables?

Then -out of curiosity- I tried the following (using *meteor add simple:reactive-method*) and it works:

```
Template.customerDashboard.helpers({
    getProductsCount: function () {
        return ReactiveMethod.call("getProductsCount");
    }
});
```

So the question really is why having to use Reactive variables and methods for sth as simple as this. Can someone explain?

Comment: [This question is too vague and is not suitable for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).  However the [publish-counts](https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/publish-counts) package may help you.

Comment: You should also look at [msavin:mongol](https://atmospherejs.com/msavin/mongol) as a great example of doing this. His code is on github too.

Comment: I have updated the original question to make it more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the `count` only in the view, the best way is to return the count number only. you do not need publish/subscribe at all. you can use server methods. and if you want to show data also, you can go for pub-sub. and your approach is correct.